# Not able to launch web browser in "Cucumber-Groovy-geb-maven" project

Tags: java, maven, grails, groovy

this is Vinayak. I have created Cucumber-Groovy-geb-maven project. I have done the set up very well as provided on the portal but facing an issue while launching the browser. I am not able to find out the solution. Could anyone please assist me?

RunCuketest.groovy

```
package runner

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import cucumber.api.junit.*;
import org.junit.*;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.runtime.junit.*;
import cucumber.runtime.*;
import cucumber.api.*    
import org.junit.Test


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions (
    features = ['src/test/resources/features/'],
    tags = ['~@wip'],
    format =          ['pretty','html:build/reports/cucumber','junit:build/cucumber.xml'],
    glue = [ 'src/test/groovy/stepDefinition/']

 )
 public class RunCukeTest {

 }
```

GebConfig.groovy

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import geb.Browser;

def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
/*
  driver = {

  def driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver();
  driverInstance.manage().window().maximize();
  driverInstance
}*/


baseUrl = "http://gebish.org"

baseNavigatorWaiting = true
```

env.groovy

```
package stepDefinition

import geb.*
import geb.Browser
import geb.binding.BindingUpdater

import static cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks.After;
import static cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks.Before;

Before() {
   bindingUpdater = new BindingUpdater(binding, new Browser(baseUrl :        "http://newtours.demoaut.com/"))
  //bindingUpdater = new BindingUpdater(binding, new Browser())
  bindingUpdater.initialize()
}

After() {
 bindingUpdater.remove()
}
```

definition file

```
package stepDefinition

import geb.*
import geb.Browser;
import geb.navigator.factory.*;

import cucumber.api.groovy.EN.*;
import cucumber.api.groovy.*;
import geb.*;

this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.EN);
this.metaClass.mixin(cucumber.api.groovy.Hooks);
this.metaClass.mixin(geb.Browser);

import pages.*;
import pages.mercurySearch;


Given(~/^I am at the mercury tours home page$/) { ->
     to mercurySearch    
     at mercurySearch
}

When(~/^I enter "(.*?)" in userName field$/) { String sUName ->
    mercurySearch.txtUserName.value(sUName)
}

And(~/^I enter "(.*?)" in password field$/) { String sPwd ->
    mercurySearch.txtPassWord.value(sPwd)
}

And(~/^I click on SignIn button$/) { ->
   mercurySearch.btnSignIn.click()
}
```

Anything i have done incorrect?

Thanks.....

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Also, what's in your feature file?

Comment: What is the issue you face?